# PHP/ADODB/MySQL: is it possible to use named placeholders in prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement, adodb

As far as I know, MySQL does not support named placeholders in prepared statements directly. So, you can't write something like this:

```
SET @s = 'SELECT SQRT(POW(:a,2) + POW(:b,2)) AS hypotenuse';
PREPARE stmt2 FROM @s;
SET @a = 6;
SET @b = 8;
EXECUTE stmt2 USING @a, @b;
```

But it's possible to do that using for instance PDO. For example:

```
$a = 6;
$b = 8;
$stmt = $conn->dbh->prepare('SELECT SQRT(POW(:a,2) + POW(:b,2)) AS hypotenuse;');
$stmt = bindParam(':a', $a);
$stmt = bindParam(':b', $b);
$stmt->execute();
```

I wonder if this possible with ADODB too because I plan to start using ADODB shortly.

Comment: I've read this: _For most databases, the bind placeholder is "?". However some databases use named bind parameters such as Oracle, eg ":somevar"._ But what about MySQL?

Comment: "Bind parameters are denoted by ?, except for the oci8 driver, which uses the traditional Oracle :varname convention. "

Comment: Pity that it's not possible. Thank you anyway.